# Find pattern and wrap between parenthesis the next letter

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have to find different patterns in a data frame column, once it is found, the next letter should be wrapped between parentheses:

Data:

```
a <- c('(acetyl)RKJOEQLKQ', 'LDFEION(acetyl)EFNEOW')
```

if the pattern is: `'(acetyl)'`
this is the output that I'd like to achieve:

Expected output:

```
b <- c('(R)KJOEQLKQ', 'LDFEION(E)FNEOW')
```

I know how that I can  find the pattern with gsub:

```
b <- gsub('(acetyl)', replacement = '', a)
```

However, I'm not sure how to approach the wrapping between the parenthesis of the next letter after the pattern is found.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
a <- c('(acetyl)RKJOEQLKQ', 'LDFEION(acetyl)EFNEOW')
gsub('\\(acetyl\\)(.)', '(\\1)', a)
## => [1] "(R)KJOEQLKQ"     "LDFEION(E)FNEOW"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rNk3yd/1) and the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/qsxAQZ).

*Details*:

- `\(acetyl\)` - matches a literal string `(acetyl)`
- `(.)` - captures into Group 1 any single char

The `(\1)` replacement pattern replaces the matches with `(` + Group 1 value + `)`.

Comment: FYI: if you really need to match a *letter* after `(acetyl)`, replace `(.)` with `([[:alpha:]])`, although your input strings look as if they all can only contain a letter after the searched string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Wiktor the '(\\1)' works perfectly.  Soon will be time for me to study some regex :P